# Ruby gsub / regex modifiers?

Tags: ruby, regex

Where can I find the documentation on the modifiers for `gsub`? \a \b \c \1 \2 \3 %a %b %c $1 $2 %3 etc.?

Specifically, I'm looking at this code... `something.gsub(/%u/, unit)` what's the `%u`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zenspider's Quickref contains a section explaining [which escape sequences can be used in regexen](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#11) and one listing the [pseudo variables](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#17) that get set by a regexp match. In the second argument to gsub you simply write the name of the variable with a backslash instead of a $ and it will be replaced with the value of that variable after applying the regexp. If you use a double quoted string, you need to use two backslashes.

When using the block-form of gsub you can simply use the variables directly. If you return a string containing e.g. \1 from the block, that will not be replaced with $1. That only happens when using the two-argument form.

Comment: I'm looking at this code... .gsub(/%u/, unit) what's the %u? I can't seem to find %u in your docs, and The explanation for % is not clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: The %u is a percent sign followed by the letter u. It has no special meaning in regexen, so I assume that the text literally contains that sequence.

Answer (score 11):

First off, `%u` is nothing special in ruby regex:

```
mixonic@pandora ~ $ irb
irb(main):001:0> '%u'.gsub(/%u/,'heyhey')
=> "heyhey"
```

The definitive documentation for Ruby 1.8 regex is in the Ruby Doc Bundle:

- http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#regexp

> Strings delimited by slashes are
>   regular expressions. The characters
>   right after latter slash denotes the
>   option to the regular expression.
>   Option i means that regular expression
>   is case insensitive. Option i means
>   that regular expression does
>   expression substitution only once at
>   the first time it evaluated. Option x
>   means extended regular expression,
>   which means whitespaces and commens
>   are allowd in the expression. Option p
>   denotes POSIX mode, in which newlines
>   are treated as normal character
>   (matches with dots).
>
> The %r/STRING/ is the another form of
>   the regular expression.
>
> ```
> ^
>     beginning of a line or string 
> $
>     end of a line or string 
> .
>     any character except newline 
> \w
>     word character[0-9A-Za-z_] 
> \W
>     non-word character 
> \s
>     whitespace character[ \t\n\r\f] 
> \S
>     non-whitespace character 
> \d
>     digit, same as[0-9] 
> \D
>     non-digit 
> \A
>     beginning of a string 
> \Z
>     end of a string, or before newline at the end 
> \z
>     end of a string 
> \b
>     word boundary(outside[]only) 
> \B
>     non-word boundary 
> \b
>     backspace(0x08)(inside[]only) 
> [ ]
>     any single character of set 
> *
>     0 or more previous regular expression 
> *?
>     0 or more previous regular expression(non greedy) 
> +
>     1 or more previous regular expression 
> +?
>     1 or more previous regular expression(non greedy) 
> {m,n}
>     at least m but most n previous regular expression 
> {m,n}?
>     at least m but most n previous regular expression(non greedy) 
> ?
>     0 or 1 previous regular expression 
> |
>     alternation 
> ( )
>     grouping regular expressions 
> (?# )
>     comment 
> (?: )
>     grouping without backreferences 
> (?= )
>     zero-width positive look-ahead assertion 
> (?! )
>     zero-width negative look-ahead assertion 
> (?ix-ix)
>     turns on (or off) `i' and `x' options within regular expression.
> ```
>
> These modifiers are localized inside
>   an enclosing group (if any). 
>       (?ix-ix: )
>           turns on (or off) `i' and`x' options within this non-capturing
>   group.
>
> Backslash notation and expression
>   substitution available in regular
>   expressions.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm looking at this code... .gsub(/%u/, unit) what's the %u? I can't seem to find %u in your docs, and The explanation for % is not clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: %u is nothing special- try the code in IRB: '%u'.gsub(/%u/,'heyhey') #=> "heyhey".  gsub is finding a string '%u' and replacing it with the second argument,  'heyhey' in this example.

Answer (score 5):

If you use block in sub/gsub you can access to the groups like that :

```
>> rx = /(ab(cd)ef)/
>> s = "-abcdef-abcdef"
>> s.gsub(rx) { $2 }
=> "cdgh-cdghi"
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ruby 1.9's [Oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/) there is a good documentation of the regular expression [here](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt).

Answer (score 0):

**gsub** is also a string substitution function within the LUA language.

Within the **LUA regex** language %u represents the Upper Case character class. i.e. It will match all upper case letters. Similarly %l will match lower case.

[LUA Regex Class Patterns](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)