# ruby regex .scan

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using Ruby's scan() method to find text in a particular format. I then output it into a string separated by commas. The text I'm trying to find would look like this:

`AB_ABCD_123456`

Here's the what I've come up with so far to find the above. It works fine:

```
text.scan(/.._...._[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)
puts text.uniq.sort.join(', ')
```

Now I need a regex that will find the above with or without a two-letter country designation at the end. For example, I would like to be able to find all three of the below:

`AB_ABCD_123456`
`AB_ABCD_123456UK`
`AB_ABCD_123456DE`

I know I could use two or three different scans to achieve my result, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get all three with one regex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
/.._...._[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](?:[A-Z][A-Z])?/
```

You can also use {} to make the regex shorter:

```
/.{2}_.{4}_[0-9]{6}(?:[A-Z]{2})?/
```

Explanation: `?` makes the preceding pattern optional. `()` groups expressions together (so ruby knows the `?` applies to the two letters). The `?:` after the opening `(` makes the group non-capturing (capturing groups would change the values yielded by scan).

Answer (score 1):

```
 /.._...._\d{6}([A-Z]{2})?/
```

Comment: If you don't make the group non-capturing scan will only yield the country-codes (or nil for the strings that didn't include one), not the entire string that was matched.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use split?

```
"AB_ABCD_123456".split(/_/).join(',')
```

Handles the cases you listed without modification.

Comment: AFAIK, the OP is trying to find a list of these codes ... not work with just one.

Comment: Yes; I saw the example and jumped past the details - a terrible habit. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text.scan(/\w{2}_\w{4}_\d{6}\w{0,2}/) 
#matches AB_ABCD_123456UK or ab_abcd_123456uk and so on...
```

or

```
text.scan(/[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{4}_\d{6}[A-Z]{0,2}/) 
# tighter, matches only AB_ABCD_123456UK and similars...
# and not something like ab_aBCd_123456UK or ab_abcd_123456uk and similars...
```

refer to these urls:

[Ruby gsub / regex modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234741/ruby-gsub-modifiers)

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#regexp

if you want to learn more about regex.

Comment: i like that second regex example. thanks for the links. i've gone through them, though not as thoroughly as i should. real life problems help my understanding a lot.