# How can ruby do this task (Case-insensitive string search & replace in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I have some problem with replace string in Ruby.

My Original string  : What the human does is not like what animal does.

I want to replace to: ==What== the human does is not like ==what== animal does.

I face the problem of case sensitive when using gsub. (eg. What , what) I want to keep original text.

any solution?

Comment: A better title might be, "Case-insensitive string search & replace in Ruby". Changing the title to something like that might help you get more people looking at your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this is what you want to do:

```
puts "What the human does is not like what animal does.".gsub(/(what)/i, '==\1==')
```

which will output

==What== the human does is not like ==what== animal does.

Comment: Updated example using the case insensitive flag to the regexp as was suggested by brianegge.

Answer (score 3):

another version without brackets () in regex,

```
puts "What the human does is not like what animal does.".gsub(/what/i,'==\0==')
```

==What== the human does is not like ==what== animal does.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to take account of in all 3 answers so far, is the use of the "i" modifier on the regular expression. This is the shorthand way to specify the use of the `Regexp::IGNORECASE` option.

A useful Ruby Regexp tutorial is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html) and the class is documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [block form of gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234741/ruby-gsub-regex-modifiers).

```
"What the human does is not like what animal does.".gsub(/(what)/i) { |s| "==#{s}==" }
=> "==What== the human does is not like ==what== animal does."
```

Comment: I was writing the exact same thing.
Here's the gsub documentation: 
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817